# The problem with mpirun with error "symbol lookup error: mpirun: undefined symbol: opal_libevent2022_event_base_loop"

Tags: fortran, gfortran, openmpi

I'm newbie to MPI. I try to test MPI with simple Hello_world code. I compiled the code with mpifort -c ../main.f95 -g -w -I/opt/openmpi4.0.1/include. The output file is test1.
When i used mpirun np -4 ./test1, it gave an error "mpirun: symbol lookup error: mpirun: undefined symbol: opal_libevent2022_event_base_loop
". Could you please figure out what is wrong with mpirun.

```
   program hello
   include 'mpif.h'
   integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

   call MPI_INIT(ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
   print*, 'node', rank, ': Hello world'
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
   end
```

Comment: I see that you installation is in `/opt/openmpi4.0.1`. Did you install it manually? Do you export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the subdirectory with MPI libraries? Is there any other MPI in your system?

Comment: Yes, I did it manually. I have already exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ./bashrc as  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/openmpi4.0.1/ but I didn't work. There is openmpi1.6.5 in my system which is in folder /usr/. After upgrade from Debian 8 to Debian 10, the previous version didn't work anymore so I installed openmpi4.0.1 to new folder which is /opt/openmpi4.0.1. I don't uninstall the previous openmpi.

Comment: Unless it is a typo, you should rather use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openmpi4.0.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (i.e. point it to the library directory!). Or with `lib` instead of `lib64` depending on your installation; you need to check which one is there. And add also `/opt/openmpi4.0.1/bin` to `PATH`. You don't need to specify `-I` when using the *correct* `mpifort` wrapper from `/opt/openmpi4.0.1/bin`.

Comment: Sorry, I still produced same errors although I have already tried what you suggested. I run a **ompi_info** to have more details about the current version of openmpi. In the **prefix** section it give **/usr** and ** '--prefix=/usr/local' ** for **Configure command line:** section which is very strange for me. Because I installed the openmpi in **\opt**. One more thing, I removed **-I** and the compiler gave a warning **gfortran: warning: /opt/openmpi4.0.1/include: linker input file unused because linking not done**.

Comment: I meant that you do not need to use the whole include line `-I /opt/openmpi4.0.1/include` when you use `mpifort` from `/opt/openmpi4.0.1/bin`. I think that you will do best if you just uninstall the system MPI; that will force you to set the paths to your manual installation correctly.

Comment: I see. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I will try to uninstall every openmpi version in my system. Thank you for your help.